# How to read file from s3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to read a CSV file directly from s3.

I'm getting the s3 URL but I am not able to open it as it's not in the local system. I don't want to download the file and read it.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: How do you plan on opening the file without downloading it?

Comment: Well that's certainly one way to do it! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open the file from URL directly:

```
require 'open-uri'
csv = open('http://server.com/path-to-your-file.csv').read
```

Comment: can I use that csv variable to process and read each row ?
Ex: CSV.foreach(csv)

Comment: No. `read` will read all the file at once, and csv would become a string. If you want to access lines, `open().readlines` would convert it to the array. Or you can iterate on every line: `open().each {|line| ...}`. Learn more on file reading on [Ruby for Admins: Input and Output](http://rubyforadmins.com/input-and-output#more-methods-to-read-from-io-object)

Comment: Sorry to ask you this question. The url which am getting is a csv file. I cannot use any csv operations on it if I use open().each right?. I mean accessing headers and all.

Comment: You can use `CSV::parse` method. Read [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse). Example: `CSV.parse(open('http://server.com/path-to-your-file.csv')).each {...}`

Answer (score 12):

There are few ways, depending on the gems that you are using. For example, one of the approaches from official [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/downloading-objects-from-amazon-s3-using-the-aws-sdk-for-ruby/):

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
resp = s3.get_object(bucket:'bucket-name', key:'object-key')

resp.body
#=> #<StringIO ...> 

resp.body.read
#=> '...'
```

Or if you are using CarrierWave/Fog:

```
obj = YourModel.first
content = obj.attachment.read
```

Answer (score -2):

I think s3 doesn't provide you any way of reading the file without downloading it.
What you can do is save it in a tempfile:

```
@temp_file = Tempfile.open("your_csv.csv")
@temp_file.close
`s3cmd get s3://#{@your_path} #{@temp_file.path}`
```

For further information: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html

Comment: 's3cmd get s3://#{@your_path} #{@temp_file.path}` what does this command says?

Comment: "@your_path" must be the url of your s3 directory
"@temp_file.path" is the path of the temporal file we just created.
It basically says "get the file from the url of my s3 and store it in this temporal file"